# Rails validation format for city, st

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, format

Trying to add a validation for a location to be in the format of city, state (ex. New York, NY) with the city being any length and the state being 2 characters. Found multiple resources to validate emails and specific file types, but can't get it right for city, state. Closest I came up with was for C#, but it's using ^ and $ and doesn't translate appropriately.

```
(^[\w\s]+,\s\w{2}$)
```

Answer (score 1):

if 2 characters code can only be between a-z then use this:

```
^[^,]+,\s*[a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

otherwise you can use:

```
^[^,]+,\s*\w{2}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIJ3I7/2)

Sample Source:

```
re = /^[^,]+,\s*\w{2}$/m
str = 'city, state 
New York, NY
Dhaka,DHK
California,Ca
Los Angeles, LA
'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

[Run the source code](http://ideone.com/AR56Yv)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
/([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*),? ([A-Z]{2,2})/
```